# handle undefined index crashes ?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

recently i've started using laravel. but i am wondering why it crashes and throw exception because of undefined index.

**for example:**

$arr=[];
return $arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGY0U.png);

this causing the app to crash and return code 500. this is not good at all. i don't need it to crash, it should just return null.

How could i handle this ?

other suggest to wrap each line with isset for example:

```
if(isset($arr[1]))
   return $arr[1]
```

i can't go through all my code and wrap each line with isset. that's tough work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you forgetting a `;` after `$arr[1]`? There's nothing else wrong with your code. It's either that or you're mistaking the problem.

Comment: "**that's tough work**" But if you need a flawlessly working code you shall need to handle the event of array index not being set gracefully.

Comment: If you want a null return if you try to access an undefined index in an array, then I'd suggest creating a custom error handler to trap for that; but ths isn't a Laravel issue, it's a coder issue

Comment: @Jaw.sh no i didn't forget ; . one minute i will set all the exception log

Comment: It doesn't crash. It aborts the processing. You tried to access something that doesn't exist. A `C` program would segfault there, Laravel gives you a nice warning. What you should do is **avoid writing sloppy code**. Seeing you already have sloppy code, why do you bother with a framework? If you plan on resuming with sloppy code, then don't use the framework which is trying to rectify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say it's not a code issue, but a Laravel issue..... it ***is*** a code issue, PHP issues a notice if you try to access an array element that doesn't exist.... you may choose to suppress that notice, or (as Laravel does) to report it in a clean fashion; but it is not a PHP issue, or a Laravel issue; it is a response to sloppy coding. If it runs without issue outside of Laravel, then that's because you're suppressing notices, not because it isn't an issue.

If you want a null return if you try to access an undefined index in an array, then I'd suggest creating a custom error handler to trap for that.

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if ($errno == E_NOTICE && strpos($errstr, 'Undefined offset') === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return false;
}

$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");


$arr=[];

var_dump($arr[1]);
```

Of course, you'd have to integrate that logic with Laravel's own error handling routines

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XhtD2)

Answer (score 6):

If you afraid of redundancy, you can use shortcuts:

```
echo $arr[1] ?? ''; // works in `PHP 7` only
```

For Blade:

```
{{ $arr[1] or '' }}
```

Both examples work like this code:

```
if (isset($arr[1])) {
    echo $arr[1];
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

If you're still using `PHP 5`, you can use ternary operator:

```
echo isset($arr[1]) ? $arr[1] : '';
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer i was searching for something which will return null automatically, without doing that for each line